# Tibble refuses to round numeric values

Tags: r, dataframe, rounding, tibble

I have the results of a logistic model tibble and I only want to round numeric values to 2 decimal places.

```
# A tibble: 13 x 5
   V1                                Estimate              `Std. Error`       `z value` `Pr(>|z|)`
   <chr>                             <chr>                 <chr>              <chr>     <chr>     
 1 (Intercept)                       -1.90291421811375     0.964204063296509  -1.97355~ 0.0484318~
 2 Account.Balance                   0.694128282719847     0.145259100427959  4.778552~ 1.7656139~
 3 Payment.Status.of.Previous.Credit 0.630305949182006     0.191866504792205  3.285127~ 0.0010193~
 4 Purpose                           -0.454203935313804    0.122895571752482  -3.69585~ 0.0002191~
 5 Value.Savings.Stocks              0.242083561334417     0.105635776802594  2.291681~ 0.0219240~
 6 Length.of.current.employment      0.210540938634289     0.112754178012934  1.867256~ 0.0618658~
 7 Sex...Marital.Status              0.290707163769223     0.182604852302629  1.592001~ 0.1113844~
 8 Most.valuable.available.asset     -0.224255567319384    0.124537400354927  -1.80070~ 0.0717488~
 9 Type.of.apartment                 0.0181184073163798    0.240544916499096  0.075322~ 0.9399582~
10 Concurrent.Credits                0.5157296191602       0.285021547837456  1.809440~ 0.0703825~
11 Duration.of.Credit..month.        -0.0222088565160083   0.0110414252703511 -2.01141~ 0.0442819~
12 Credit.Amount                     -8.35954153767761e-05 4.89225782908274e~ -1.70872~ 0.0875012~
13 Age..years.                       0.00608936013808303   0.0113785935909403 0.535159~ 0.5925397~
```

No matter what I try (convert to a dataframe, then manually round each `fit0.sum[row,col]` value; `%>% mutate_if(., is.numeric, round2)` where `round2 <- function(y) {round(y,2)}`) I still get the same result whether as a tibble

```
# A tibble: 13 x 5
   V1                                Estimate              `Std. Error`       `z value` `Pr(>|z|)`
   <chr>                             <chr>                 <chr>              <chr>     <chr>     
 1 (Intercept)                       -1.90291421811375     0.964204063296509  -1.97355~ 0.0484318~
 2 Account.Balance                   0.694128282719847     0.145259100427959  4.778552~ 1.7656139~
 3 Payment.Status.of.Previous.Credit 0.630305949182006     0.191866504792205  3.285127~ 0.0010193~
 4 Purpose                           -0.454203935313804    0.122895571752482  -3.69585~ 0.0002191~
 5 Value.Savings.Stocks              0.242083561334417     0.105635776802594  2.291681~ 0.0219240~
 6 Length.of.current.employment      0.210540938634289     0.112754178012934  1.867256~ 0.0618658~
 7 Sex...Marital.Status              0.290707163769223     0.182604852302629  1.592001~ 0.1113844~
 8 Most.valuable.available.asset     -0.224255567319384    0.124537400354927  -1.80070~ 0.0717488~
 9 Type.of.apartment                 0.0181184073163798    0.240544916499096  0.075322~ 0.9399582~
10 Concurrent.Credits                0.5157296191602       0.285021547837456  1.809440~ 0.0703825~
11 Duration.of.Credit..month.        -0.0222088565160083   0.0110414252703511 -2.01141~ 0.0442819~
12 Credit.Amount                     -8.35954153767761e-05 4.89225782908274e~ -1.70872~ 0.0875012~
13 Age..years.                       0.00608936013808303   0.0113785935909403 0.535159~ 0.5925397~
```

or dataframe

```
V1              Estimate           Std. Error
1                        (Intercept)     -1.90291421811375    0.964204063296509
2                    Account.Balance     0.694128282719847    0.145259100427959
3  Payment.Status.of.Previous.Credit     0.630305949182006    0.191866504792205
4                            Purpose    -0.454203935313804    0.122895571752482
5               Value.Savings.Stocks     0.242083561334417    0.105635776802594
6       Length.of.current.employment     0.210540938634289    0.112754178012934
7               Sex...Marital.Status     0.290707163769223    0.182604852302629
8      Most.valuable.available.asset    -0.224255567319384    0.124537400354927
9                  Type.of.apartment    0.0181184073163798    0.240544916499096
10                Concurrent.Credits       0.5157296191602    0.285021547837456
11        Duration.of.Credit..month.   -0.0222088565160083   0.0110414252703511
12                     Credit.Amount -8.35954153767761e-05 4.89225782908274e-05
13                       Age..years.   0.00608936013808303   0.0113785935909403
              z value             Pr(>|z|)
1   -1.97355963384752   0.0484318374754513
2    4.77855281132007 1.76561390890261e-06
3    3.28512759360806  0.00101936198109079
4   -3.69585273770966  0.00021914997861395
5     2.2916815558313   0.0219240254873804
6    1.86725620588656   0.0618658179663915
7    1.59200130830826    0.111384410585524
8    -1.8007085958135   0.0717488220562993
9  0.0753223455314545    0.939958242819384
10   1.80944080569766   0.0703825485583934
11  -2.01141211140962   0.0442819451207211
12  -1.70872873624589    0.087501208575445
13  0.535159296218421    0.592539709935268
```

Answer (score 2):

All your columns are *character* , not *numeric*! That is why `mutate_if(., is.numeric, round2)` does not find any columns with `is.numeric == TRUE` and thus does not mutate anything.

Comment: derp.... I feel dumb now

Comment: I have posted some code here to find, which entries are the culprits for the reading functions not detecting a column as numeric. Even though the post is in German, the code might be usefull in detecting why this was read as `<chr>`: http://forum.r-statistik.de/viewtopic.php?t=3516